# Python: can't data streaming beetwen raspberry pi and notebook with ubuntu with socket module and udp protocol

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, udp

i am trying to create a connection between a laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) and a raspberry (Raspbian) to stream the value of one variable (exactly the value of the object that is detected by the webcam on the laptop, it works based on the detection API from tensorflow).

I use the **socket** module for this process and I wanted to use the **UDP** protocol to facilitate the whole process.

The program that sends the information looks like this (it is located on the laptop, which also has a program to detect objects):

```
UDP_IP = '192.168.0.13'
UDP_PORT = 12345

while True:

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    sock.sendto((str(objects[0])+str(datetime.now())).encode("utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    sock.close()
```

where `objects[0]` is an element whose value I want to send in a continuous stream.
The program to receive data on raspberry looks like this:

```
import socket
import time


UDP_PORT = 12345
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), UDP_PORT))


while True:
  time.sleep(0.1)
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048) # b'eframe' is 6 byte long
  print(str(data))
```

I will add that if I want to send data locally, i.e. the receiving program is not on raspberry but on the same computer from which I sending data (of course after changing the IP). I also pinged raspberry from a laptop to check if the IP is ok.

```
piotr@peter:~$ ping 192.168.0.13
PING 192.168.0.13 (192.168.0.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=7.08 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=6.57 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=42.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=11.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=10.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=8.02 ms
```

I have problem because, for this moment when I start the transfer data process beetwen raspberry and laptop. Raspberry can open the port but doesn't receive any data.

I don't know what might be wrong.

Comment: You haven't stated a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I lost one sentence that I wanted to write. Already added